# Order of execution of instructions in a script shell

Tags: shell, script

Here is a portion of my script test.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

tar -cf $name.tar $name && pbzip2 $name.tar
echo "[$1: Waiting..]
```

Please, i have a question. The execution of the second instruction "echo" is just after the creation of the file .tar.bz2 ? as i see no. I see that i have only the tar directory and the instruction echo is launched !

Any explanation please ?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you're trying to say that the `echo` is executed, but you do not see the result of `pbzip2`, then either the first `tar` does not return `0` (and then `pbzip2` is not executed at all), or the `pbzip2` command is wrong or it compresses the file "in place" (so overwriting the original `.tar` file rather than creating a new file with a `.bz2` extension).

Comment: echo is executed, but you do not see the result of pbzip2   That's it, i have to send this file pbzip2 to a destination node, but it is sended corrupt

Answer (score 1):

The `echo` command is not executed as long as the **prior packing and compression command is not done**.

Meaning, no output until the file is packed and compressed. If you want some kind of output to show when it starts and when it is done use:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "[$1: Packing]"
tar -cf $name.tar $name && pbzip2 $name.tar
echo "[$1: Done]"
```

Comment: "echo is executed, but you do not see the result of pbzip2 "                That's it, i have to send this file pbzip2 to a destination node, but it is sended corrupt